# Is it possible to restore windows status after maximum window?

Tags: vim, editor

I always have this problem. When a windows seems too small to view code, i will type `:only` the maximum this window and hide other windows. But when the editing is finished i quit want to restore the previous status of windows. Exactly the same before i maximum one window. It there any plugin to do this job? Or it's build-in in vim?

**EDIT**: I found a plugin called ZoomWin can actually do this job. But 0 can't been map to `:ZoomWin` in my vim. Still don't know why. The help file says i can use 0 to call Zoomvim just after i installing this plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably write a script using `mkview` and `loadview` if you wanted to keep this all in one tab, however, this is the exact thing that vim's tabs were made for.  I suggest using the following mapping to map `\0` to open the current buffer in a new tab.  To close the tab just do `:q` as you would normally do and you'll go back to your previous tab which contains the window layout you want.

```
:nnoremap <leader>0 :tabedit %<cr>
```

Note that this mapping uses `<leader>` so if you've changed your mapleader then the sequence will not be `\0`.